# Como hacer el código más limpio? JS JQ

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `if` dentro de un evento `submit`. Realizo una condición para indicar que si lo `inputs` y los `select` no están vacíos pues ejecute cierta función.

Como esto:

```
$('#formulario').submit(function (e) {
    if($("#id").val()!=="" && $("#name").val()!=="" && $("#surname").val()!=="" && $("#city").val()!=="") {

     //código 
    }
});
```

La cuestión es que pueden ser mas de 10 inputs y select's y escribir eso para todos esta como mal. Como puedo hacer el código mas limpio? Agradezco la colaboración.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías realizar la siguiente estrategia

```
$('#formulario').submit(function (e) {
  let selectors = [
    "#id",
    "#name",
    "#surname",
    "#city"
  ];

  for (const selector of selectors) {
    if ($(selector).val() === "") return;
  }

  // Código

});
```

Almacenas en un arreglo todos los selectores que tienes que analizar, los recorres en un ciclo y revisas que si la cadena es vacía no ejecutarás más código, por lo cual te saldrías de la función y no retornarás nada, en caso que todos los valores de tus selectores cumplan con el hecho de que tienen contenido, se ejecutará el código que iría luego del `for`.

Comment: Se ajusta a lo que busco, muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Que te parece por medio de una clase a cada campo que quieras validar, te dejo mi ejemplo.

Espero te ayude en algo.

```js
$('#formulario').submit(function (e) {


//buscamos los campos con clase "valida" para comparar su valor
$('#formulario .valida').each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
//validamos valor
   if (element.val() == "") {
   //tu codigo en caso de tener algun vacio
   //muestra un mensaje al usuario del campo vacio mediante su propiedad name
       alert(element.prop('name')+ ' Campo Vacio ');
       e.preventDefault();
   //retornamos false ya que se encontro un campo vacio para no continuar con las demas validaciones.
      return false; 
   }
});

//tu codigo que quieres ejecutar si no se encontraron vacios.

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="#" >
  <p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" class="valida" size="40"></p>
  <p>Año de nacimiento: <input type="number" name="FechaNacimiento"  class="valida" min="1"></p>
  <p>Lista
   <select id="select1" name="lista" class="valida" >
   <option value="" selected></option>
   <option value="1" >valor 1</option>
   <option value="2" >valor 2</option>
   </select>
   
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
   
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un each dentro de tu submit que recorra los inputs a ser validados que contengan class="classValid"

Ejemplo:

```
$('#formulario').submit(function (e) {
    $(this).find(".classValid").each(function(i){//recoorre todos los inputs del formulario con class=classValid
        if($(this).val().length <= 0)
            return false;
    });
    //tu codigo
});
```

si se quiere recorrer solo algunos tipos de inputs

```
find('input[input:text, input:radio, select]')
```

o todos los input existentes dentro del formulario incluye button

```
find(':input')//
```